# How can I show the data from an XML file in a table in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to show the data from the xml file into the tables, so I can see them and add/delete/edit with ease.
The use of 
    DataGridView 
would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you using ASP.NET or Window Forms ?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net ,Using Gridview,add namespace and code below,

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(MapPath("~/App_Data/examplefile1.xml"));

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

in windows datagridview.add namespaces and code below,

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;

 XmlReader xmlFile ;
                xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("examplefile1.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

working fine.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way I saw on the Internet, courtesy of Vetrivel D (source: http://tinyurl.com/VetrivelD)

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.TableName = "JobDetails";
        dt1.Columns.Add("JobNum");
        dt1.Columns.Add("Detail1");
        dt1.Columns.Add("Detail2");

        ds.Tables.Add(dt1);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataRow row1 = ds.Tables["JobDetails"].NewRow();
            row1["JobNum"] = r.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            row1["Detail1"] = r.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            row1["Detail2"] = r.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            ds.Tables["JobDetails"].Rows.Add(row1); 
        }
        ds.WriteXml("..\\..\\..\\xmlSample.xml");
```

And for the loading, he had this:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("..\\..\\..\\xmlSample.xml");

        foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["JobDetails"].Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value =     item["JobNum"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["Detail1"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["Detail2"].ToString();
        }
```

I want to highlight, I just rewrote the code I saw on the internet, with the source included.